# Asp.Net MVC, WebApi and Correct Asynchronous Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, task, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a multi layered web application and recently I decided to convert my service layer (WebApi in this case) to asynchronous processing.

In this regard, I converted all my WebApi methods to implement Tasks and in MVC part, I implemented a business layer which make calls to the WebApi.

My MVC controllers simply use the business layer classes to get view data.

I'm sort of new to this Task based programming in .Net 4.5 and want to know if my approach is correct or flawed. In my simple tests, I've seen a performance increase in response times but I'm not sure if all my asynchronous calls are safe or prone to errors.

Code samples:

**WebApi action:**

```
[Route("category/withnews/{count:int=5}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<NewsCategoryDto>> GetNewsCategoriesWithRecentNews(int count)
        {
            return await Task.Run<IEnumerable<NewsCategoryDto>>(() =>
                {
                    using (var UoW = new UnitOfWork())
                    {
                        List<NewsCategoryDto> returnList = new List<NewsCategoryDto>();

                        var activeAndVisibleCategories = UoW.CategoryRepository.GetActiveCategories().Where(f => f.IsVisible == true);
                        foreach (var category in activeAndVisibleCategories)
                        {
                            var dto = category.MapToDto();
                            dto.RecentNews = (from n in UoW.NewsRepository.GetByCategoryId(dto.Id).Where(f => f.IsVisible == true).Take(count)
                                              select n.MapToDto(true)).ToList();

                            returnList.Add(dto);
                        }

                        return returnList;
                    }
                });
        }
```

**Business class method to call this api (NewsService class in MVC app.)**

```
public async Task<IndexViewModel> GetIndexViewModel()
        {
            var model = new IndexViewModel();

            using (var stargate = new StargateHelper())
            {
                string categoriesWithNews = await stargate.InvokeAsync("news/category/withnews/" + model.PreviewNewsMaxCount).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var objectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewsCategoryDto>>(categoriesWithNews);

                model.NewsCategories = objectData;
            }

            return model;
        }
```

**MVC Controller Action to get ViewModel**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            _service.ActiveMenuItem = "";

            var viewModel = await _service.GetIndexViewModel();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

However, some of the Controller actions are PartialViewResults and as they are ChildActions, I can't convert them to async actions like the Index action. What I do in that case is:

```
var viewModel = _service.GetGalleryWidgetViewModel().Result;
return PartialView(viewModel);
```

Is it the correct way to call an asynchronous method from a synchronous method?

Adding **StargateHelper.InvokeAsync** for reference too:

```
public async Task<string> InvokeAsync(string path)
    {
        var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_baseUrl + path).ConfigureAwait(false);
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using (var responseStream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var decompStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompStream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the standard rules is to not use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. Instead, you should be using naturally-asynchronous APIs.

E.g. in your WebAPI, assuming you're using EF6:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<NewsCategoryDto>> GetNewsCategoriesWithRecentNews(int count)
{
  using (var UoW = new UnitOfWork())
  {
    List<NewsCategoryDto> returnList = new List<NewsCategoryDto>();

    var activeAndVisibleCategories = UoW.CategoryRepository.GetActiveCategories().Where(f => f.IsVisible == true);
    foreach (var category in activeAndVisibleCategories)
    {
      var dto = category.MapToDto();
      dto.RecentNews = await (from n in UoW.NewsRepository.GetByCategoryId(dto.Id).Where(f => f.IsVisible == true).Take(count)
          select n.MapToDto(true)).ToListAsync();
      returnList.Add(dto);
    }

    return returnList;
  }
}
```

Your service helpers mostly look good. Tip: if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` once in a method, it should be used everywhere in that method.

Child actions are a trouble spot with the current MVC; there is no good way to do them. ASP.NET vNext MVC has async-compatible "ViewComponents", which fill this niche. But for today, you have to choose one of two imperfect options:

1. Use a blocking `Task.Result` and avoid the deadlock issue by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. The problem with this approach is that if you accidentally forget to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere it needs to be used, then you can easily cause a deadlock again (and it would be the kind of thing where the async actions will work perfectly but the same code accessed by a child action would deadlock, so unit tests may not catch it and code coverage is misleading).
2. Duplicate all service methods required by child actions with synchronous equivalents. This approach also has a maintenance problem: the service logic is duplicated.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very informative. I'm using ConfigureAwait(false) all the way from service helpers to HttpClient wrapper, should I use it on controller calls to helpers too? Also, unfortunately this project is still using EF 5 so async data layer is kind of not supported atm. I'll upgrade the data layer soon but until then Task.Run has to work. Does it have too much impact on performance or is it just a 'rule' in task based programming?

Comment: The guideline for `ConfigureAwait(false)` is to use it everywhere you can. This is usually the service/domain layer, but usually not controller methods (controller helper methods like `View` build the response, so they need the request/response context). `Task.Run` is detrimental in ASP.NET; it removes all the benefit you get from `async` and then damages the performance a little more. However, if it's just temporary and you are definitely moving to EF6 (removing all instances of `Task.Run` at that time), then I suppose it's acceptable. :) `Task.Run` is fine in UI apps, just not on ASP.NET.

Comment: Ah I see, now I'm more confident on how and where to use ConfigureAwait(false) :) I'll get rid of all Task.Run calls as soon as I migrate to EF6. Thank you Stephen.